# Tab Bar not recognising ViewControllers when they are embedded in Navigation Controllers swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, interface-builder

I have an arrangement of views in my interface builder (image).

**Red:** My root TabBarController that segues to...
**Yellow:** My UINavControllers that have embedded...
**Green:** View Controllers

[image: view arrangement]

I was trying to add code to TabBarController.swift to change how my ViewControllers.swift are presented (modal presentation code).

In TabBarController.swift

```swift
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        if viewController is CreationViewController {
            
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CreationVC")
            
            controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("hello")
        } else { print("spaghet") }
    }
}
```

When running my application, the code is not recognised when I touch the CreationViewController tab bar item, even though the CreationViewController is being presented. Console prints "spaghet" not "hello".

So I changed the line

```swift
if viewController is CreationViewController
```

to

```swift
if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1
```

and it now works.
I don't understand why the view is not being recognised when I am using "if ViewController is CreationViewController", and why it is only being recognised when I use "TabBarController.selectedIndex". It is as if the Tab Bar Controller does not recognise what View it is on. By the way, I have provided the correct class (CreationViewController) and Storyboard ID to the ViewController in Interface Builder (the green circled one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the presented view controller by UITabBarController is actually UINavigationController. So it is not matching the class when you check it with

```
if viewController is CreationViewController
```

You can test it by simply printing the view controller you get from 'func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController)' or putting a break point to that function.

Answer (score 1):

The tab bar controller is holding a `UINavigationController`, which may or may not be holding your `CreationViewController`.

You want to test for it like this:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

    // make sure the selected tab contains a UINavigationController
    guard let navVC = viewController as? UINavigationController else {
        print("Selected tab does not contain a navigation controller")
        return
    }
    if navVC.visibleViewController is CreationViewController {
        print("CreationViewController is showing in selected tab's navigation controller")
        // do something
    } else {
        print("Some other controller is showing in selected tab's navigation controller")
        // do something else
    }

}
```